# Parsing OrderedDict

Tags: python, parsing, ordereddictionary

I've been trying to parse this OrderedDict to get the 'Id' value from the following return of a SQL.

```
OrderedDict([
    ('totalSize', 1), 
    ('done', True), 
    ('records', [OrderedDict([
        ('attributes', OrderedDict([
        ('type', 'Device__c'), 
        ('url', '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Device__c/a001r00000qCgp1AAC')])), 
        ('Id', 'a001r00000qCgp1AAC')])])])
```

The following is the `print(query_result['records'])`. How can I go further?

```
 OrderedDict([
        ('attributes', OrderedDict([
            ('type', 'Device__c'), 
            ('url', '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Device__c/a001r00000qCgp1AAC')])), 
            ('Id', 'a001r00000qCgp1AAC')])]
```

Grateful for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the `records` Key

**Ex:**

```
for i in query_result["records"]: 
    print( i["Id"] )
```

---

*Or if you only have one element in the list you can use index.*

**Ex:**

```
print( query_result["records"][0]["Id"])
```